# implementing customised user registration in asp.net mvc 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-membership

i am developing a site in asp.net mvc 2.0.Now i have to implement customised user registration
page by adding extra fields.i am using following code to create the user,

```
Membership.CreateUser(userName, password);
Roles.AddUserToRole(userName, "User");
UserProfile.NewUser.Initialize(userName, true);
UserProfile.NewUser.FirstName = firstName;
UserProfile.NewUser.LastName = lastName;
UserProfile.NewUser.Save();
```

here somehow i can create the user but it cannot validate the `userName` duplication. According to mvc 2.0 built-in create user functionality it will check the status. So it will display the error if duplicate `userName` occurs.
But in my case how to validate the uniqueness of the `userName`.

Comment: Which provider are you using?

Comment: i am using sql membership provider

Comment: oh i am sorry,i am using AspNetSqlMembershipProvider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Membership API has built in functionality for dupe usernames, you just need to handle it:

```
try
{
    MembershipUser newUser = Membership.CreateUser(username, password);

}
catch (MembershipCreateUserException e)
{
   if (e.StatusCode == MembershipCreateStatus.DuplicateUserName)
      // Add to ModelState, or handle it however you want
}
```

**MembershipCreateUserException** has a property called **StatusCode** which is an enumeration of all the different **MembershipCreateStatus** error codes.

You should enhance the above code to cater for *all* the different scenarios, and act accordingly.

HTH

Comment: Great. glad you got it sorted. :)